# SAP B1 HANA systemctl Exec format error when trying to run service

Tags: linux, sapb1

[image]

Suddenly our SAP B1 running on HANA (SuSE Linux) not working, which is very weird. But after checking some possible issue, we found this error.

**sapb1servertools.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/init.d/sapb1servertools: Exec format error**
**The error number returned by this process is 8**

See image. We cannot re-install the B1 since we have so many applications that connected to it. What else we can do for the issue?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Oh, @GillesQuenot sorry about that. But the error is actually in the question. :)